# What is the efficent way to convert a Pandas DataFrame to a PyTorch TensorDataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch

I want to convert this Pandas DataFrame to a TensorDataset

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 'B': [0, 1, 0]})
```

I figured out I can do it this way without getting an error.

```
A = torch.tensor(df['A'].values.tolist())
B = torch.tensor(df['B'].values)
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(A, B)
```

However, I get the Warning:

> UserWarning: Creating a tensor from a list of numpy.ndarrays is
> extremely slow. Please consider converting the list to a single
> numpy.ndarray with numpy.array() before converting to a tensor.

When I try it this way:

```
data_numpy = df.to_numpy()
data_tensor = torch.from_numpy(data_numpy)
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(data_tensor)
```

I get the error:

> can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_

So the question arises, what is the efficient way to convert a Pandas Data Frame with this structure to a TensorDataset?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import torch


def get_device() -> torch.device:
    return torch.device("cuda:0") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")


def df_to_tensor(x: pd.DataFrame) -> torch:
    return torch.from_numpy(x.values).to(get_device())


df = pd.DataFrame({"spam": [1, 2, 3, 4], "eggs": [5, 6, 7, 8], "ham": [9, 10, 11, 12]})
tensor = df_to_tensor(df)
print(tensor)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 2,  6, 10],
        [ 3,  7, 11],
        [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Jason. Your solution works flawlessly with your DataFrame. However, it does not work with my provided DataFrame. My DataFrame contains lists and ints. Any Idea how to solve this?